# Replace state on Ionic link click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic and I have a template with a code like this:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="model in models" href="#/app/ctrl/{{model.id}}">
    {{model.name}}
</ion-item>
```

When I click the link, the state is changed to another view. Everything is fine.

But how do I replace the current view with the new one without keeping it on history?

I have the following code, which works in a controller:

```
$ionicHistory.currentView($ionicHistory.backView());
$state.go('app.products', {location: 'replace'});
```

But I don't know how to achive the same clicking on the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this docs site](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref) you can try this:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="model in models" 
          ui-sref="name.of.state" 
          ui-sref-opts="{location: 'replace'}">
    {{model.name}}
</ion-item>
```